# view resets when keyboard appears. ios 7

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, uiview

I'm writing an app where the controls provided can be hidden when required by the user to type  text on the screen. the UI hides itself when the user taps the toolbar. but when he taps the text area all the changes made automatically undo themselves. the code just creates a textbox where the user taps and lets him type.

This is the first screen.
[image: This is the first screen.]

This is after the UI is hidden
[image: This is after the UI is hidden]

And.. this is when the keyboard appears... the entire ui just pops up immediately.
[image]

Can anyone please tell my why this happens. and why my view resets everytime the keyboard shows. 
Thanks.

Comment: my best guess is you did something badly but it is very hard to tell what you've done without seeing your code.

Comment: What kind of view is it ? Scroll view ?